# How to control MKR1000 from outside your local network

Tags: http, mkr1000

I want to send an HTTP command to MKR1000 from outside my local network.

So far, all the googled resources point to getting the local IP (example 192.168.0.10) of MKR1000 and sending a command like `http://192.168.0.10/H` to it and then parse it.

How do I send a command to MKR1000 from outside its local network?

I should clarify that I want this to be a consumer product and can't have the end-user fiddling with their routers for port forwarding etc.

Comment: Google "port forwarding" along with the make and model of your router.

Comment: I want it to be a consumer product and don't want every end user to be fiddling with their router. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Well you can't. Simple fact: devices on an internal network, regardless of how you may wish it, are not accessible from outside. Only the user can configure their router to forward access to it.

Comment: But a lot of consumer IOT products (e.g. NEST) are controlled from your mobile device from anywhere?

Comment: No they aren't. An external service is controlled from your device, and the IoT device queries that same external service.

Comment: What you *really* want is something like MQTT

Comment: I see, so I need a server. Mobile device writes to server and MKR1000 keeps querying the server to get commands? I think Firebase will work nicely BUT this continuous query on MKR1000 side will be battery and data consuming.

Comment: Depends how "continuous" you really need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of to achieve this would be to port forward your router, and forward port 80 (http) to your MKR1000. You can check out https://portforward.com/ for instructions on that.

If you don't want to port-forward, you'd have to have the MKR1000 connect to a centralized IOT server somewhere, and have the user go through the server to access the MKR1000. That's how other iot devices such as nest cameras do it.

Answer (score 2):

You **now** can try this [**UPnP_Generic library**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/UPnP_Generic) to do the auto-portforwarding for you without manually touching the router.

---

---

Many of us are **manually port-forwarding** in Internet Gateway Device (IGD, Router) in order to provide access to local Web Services from the Internet.

This library provides the easier way to automatically port-forward by using the [**Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP)**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cai-ssdp-v1-03), running on nRF52, SAMD21/SAMD51, STM32F/L/H/G/WB/MP1, Teensy, ESP8266/ESP32, using ESP WiFi, WiFiNINA, Ethernet W5x00, ESP8266/ESP32 AT-command WiFi supporting **UDP Multicast**.

The SSDP provides a mechanism whereby network clients, with little or no static configuration, can discover network services. SSDP accomplishes this by providing for multicast discovery support as well as server based notification and discovery routing.

The [**SSDP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) is used for **advertisement and discovery of network services and presence information**. It accomplishes the task without assistance of server-based configuration mechanisms, such as Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) or Domain Name System (DNS), and without special static configuration of a network host. SSDP is the basis of the discovery protocol of **Universal Plug and Play (UPnP)** and is intended for use in residential or small office environments.

This [**UPnP_Generic library**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/UPnP_Generic) is created to automatically **update your IGDs with the requested port-forward information**, using one of the many available boards / shields. See [**Currently Supported Boards**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/UPnP_Generic#currently-supported-boards).

The time between checks to update the UPnP Port Mappings is **configurable** to match your use case, and is set in the examples at 10 minutes. The LEASE_DURATION is also configurable and default to 10hrs (36000s). The Virtual Server Name can also be specified in the sketch and is shown in the IGD, e.g. `NRF52-W5X00` or `ESP8266-WIFI` as in the following picture:

[image]

The UPnP_Generic code is very short, can be immersed in your Projects and to be called in the loop() code.